# Does Microsoft IoT Central send data through an Azure IoT Hub...?

Tags: azure, azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-central

I am just reading up on the new IoT Central, currently in preview.
Our customers seldom let their devices connect to cloud by themselves,
but are rather connected to some kind of management system that in turn connects to Azure.

We however consider using IoT Central for demo purposes and would like to know if devices defined in IoT Central sends their data to an IoT Hub of choice or if is handled in any other way behind the scenes?

Answer (score 7):

Microsoft IoT Central does use an IoT Hub internally. If you look here you can see that when you add a physical device to an IoT Central application it generates an IoT Hub device connection string: https://learn.microsoft.com/microsoft-iot-central/tutorial-add-device#get-connection-string-for-real-device-from-application.
However, you cannot get admin access to the IoT Hub or use an IoT Hub of your own choosing - all you have is the device connection string.